# sending value from server to client node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am registering a user and after successful registration I want alert something in client side. So, what I do in server side, after registration I'm sending a value "registered" then when it gets that value, my client side would know that user is registred but I don't know how to get that value in my client side.

```
router.post('/registration', function (req, res, next) {
    var stud = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        admin: 0
    };

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne(stud, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Student inserted');
            db.close();
            res.json('registred');
        })
    })


});
```

My client side code

```
$('.MyForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
      url: '/registration',
      method: 'post',

      success: function(response){

      }
    })


  });
```

There is not very much because I don't know what to do next

Comment: how are you making the request in client side ? (jquery, angular, other ?)

Comment: Can you post your client side code?

Comment: I am using jquery to get value

Comment: Post your jQuery code then

Comment: might want to read a bit of this, to get a better understanding of the problem you're facing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: @Cauterite pushing is not necessary, as this request is initiated by the client

Comment: alrighty, i may have been slightly mislead by the question title

Answer (score 0):

All you still need to do is put the alert in the callback to the ajax request

```
success: function(response) {
    alert('User registration succeeded!')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTTP protocol, why not use its cohesive response codes to indicate which action has happened? For example:

200 - user successfully created
400 - malformed input data
409 - one of unique user's model field has been already taken

And so on. Use method 'status' on response object to set appropriate return code. I assume that you are trying to create server with REST's rules in mind, therefore your endpoint should return freshly created entity on POST request.

```
mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('user-data').insertOne(stud, function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
              /* At this point, you may decide to check what error has been returned to decide which code will be returned*/
              return res.status(400).json(err);
            }
            console.log('Student inserted');
            db.close();
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
    })
```

On client side, code might be much more pleasant to eye after you would refactor it to use jQuery's ( since ver. 1.5.1 )'Promise API'

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8000',
  method: 'POST'
})
  .done(function( data ) {

  })
  .fail(function (reason) {

  })
```

Comment: I think thats a great idea but I am failing to realize it. I wrote on those .done and .fail functions alerts and after submit I get {"n":1,"ok":1} json values in another page

Comment: Could you please attach code snippet? Would be handy.